# Word to describe "a person who has no Love no Hate"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do we call a person who has a neutral state of mind with no Love no hate? Please don't tell a Robot or Dead Person.

Is there any word to describe a person.

Comment: Maybe "apathetic."

Comment: Are you only concerned about those two emotions? "Love" and "hate"? What about other emotions? Can this person **feel** other emotions like anger, sorrow, etc? Is this person truly not feeling any of these or is this person not **showing** these emotions? Details, details, details ...

Comment: @AIQ The person feels "neutral"  in all emotions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few options you can use. But you should pay attention to what you are really looking for. A person who does not "feel" emotions is very different from a person who does not "show" them. There is a great overlap between the two though. Also note that some of these words may not be commonly used in everyday speech, which means that they may be inappropriate for certain audiences or settings.

If you are not sure about the words and their usage, you can always use the phrase "devoid of emotions".

**1. emotionless**

> showing, having, or expressing no emotion (M-W)

**2. apathetic**

> having or showing little or no feeling or emotion : SPIRITLESS (M-W)

**3. phlegmatic**

> A phlegmatic person does not usually get emotional or excited about things (Cambridge)

**4. cold-blooded**

> a: done or acting without consideration, compunction, or clemency  (M-W)
>   // cold-blooded murder
>   b: MATTER-OF-FACT, EMOTIONLESS
>   // a cold-blooded assessment

**5. impassive**

> 1: giving no sign of feeling or emotion : EXPRESSIONLESS  (M-W)
>   2a: unsusceptible to or destitute of emotion : APATHETIC

**6. indifferent**

> 1a: marked by a lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern for something : APATHETIC (M-W)
>   //indifferent to suffering and poverty
>   b: marked by no special liking for or dislike of something
>   //indifferent about which task he was given

**7. cold**

> 2a: marked by a lack of the warmth of normal human emotion, friendliness, or compassion (M-W)
>   b: not colored or affected by personal feeling or bias : DETACHED, INDIFFERENT

You may also want to take a look at the more extreme word which may or may not suit your purpose:

**8. psychopath**

> Medical Definition of psychopath  (M-W)
>   1: a person having an egocentric and antisocial personality marked by a lack of remorse for one's actions, an absence of empathy for others, and often criminal tendencies

They are able to feel some emotions, but the most important ones are absent.

Answer (score 0):

Emotionally neutral, Disengaged.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Your posts have been flagged as low quality by the system; please [edit] them to include some references like dictionary entries.